# How do I add images to this random array?

Tags: jquery, html, css, codepen

I am wondering if it is possible to add images to the random generator so that when one clicks the button, a movie title AND a picture from the movie is displayed.

```js
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array("The Santa Claus","Just Friends","Home Alone", "Home Alone 2","Serendipity","Love Actually","Elf","Christmas Vacation","A Christmas Story","The Grinch","Jingle All the Way","Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer","Ernest Saves Christmas","Frosty the Snowman","The Muppet Christmas Carol","The Nightmare Before Christmas","Jesus of Nazareth 1977","Bad Santa");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```css
#btnSearch {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold; 
  
  }
h1 {
  text-shadow: -2px 0 green, 0 2px green, 2px 0 green, 0 -2px green;
}
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/20000/velka/green-christmas-background.jpg");
}

#generator {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff7878; 
  border: solid;
  border-color: red; 
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.fa-snowflake-o {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  
}

.fa-gift {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ff0000;
  
}

.fa-tree {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #378b29;
  
}


#message {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-family: verdana; 
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

.spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
     -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 58%;
         transform-origin:50% 58%;
         -ms-transform-origin:50% 58%; /* IE 9 */
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>  
<link 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>  
  <h1 style="text-align: center; color: red; font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold;">WHAT CHRISTMAS MOVIE SHOULD I WATCH?</h1>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
<div id="generator" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <p>
    <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o fa-5x spin"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-gift fa-5x spin"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-tree fa-5x spin"></i>
    
    </p>
  
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="What Christmas Movie Should I Watch?" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message"></p>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a second array with urls?

Comment: Would it be difficult to attach specific titles to specific images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it into a two dimensional array, then something like this should work.

```
var arr = [
        ["Movie Name 1", "Picture URL 1"],
        ["Movie Name 2", "Picture URL 2"],
        ["Movie Name 3", "Picture URL 3"],
        ["Movie Name 4", "Picture URL 4"],
        ["Movie Name 5", "Picture URL 5"]
];
var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];

document.getElementById("picture").src=random[1];
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random[0];
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, but I think this is on the right track.

Comment: You have to add a div element with the ID picture and style it the way you want. The javascript works.

Comment: Okay I added a div with the id "picture" then added your script. The urls still show up as the text of urls and not actual images and also the text from the message div shows in two places.

Comment: Sorry, straight up dumbed out on the answer. You have to add it to the `src` attribute of an `img` tag. That's how images are displayed on HTML.